# Removing Tables in plain text mode (html)

Tags: html

I have created a HTML mail signature with 7 columns (`td`) in a same row (`tr`).
But when I comes into plain text mode, the 7 columns are not deleting and the space remains still in the plain text mode.

How to remove this gap between row when it comes to plain text mode?

Ok I have put the code into the box. You can see i have inserted few columns to add 6 colors after my name. but in the text version i see large gap between my work position (Hardware technician) and the company name. this is my question. If i can sostitute this columns with (div) option, it is also a big help to me. i want to make this code more compampatible with other email clients.

```html
<html>
<body>
   
 <table class="MsoNormalTable" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family: arial;">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="height: 61px">
     <td style="width:160px;height:60px;border:none; background: #9CC2E5;padding:0px 0px 0px 2px" nowrap="nowrap" width="160">
   <div style="color: black; font-size: 16; font-weight: bold; font-family:arial;">Nirosh Chaminda<br></div>
   <div style="color: black; font-size: 12; font-style: italic;" >Hardware technician<br></b></div></td>
  <td style="width:17px;height:60px;border:none; background: #5B9BD5;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="17"></td>
  <td style="width:22px;height:60px;border:none; background: #BDD6EE;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="22"></td>
  <td style="width:32px;height:60px;border:none; background: #9CC2E5;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="32"></td>
  <td style="width:45px;height:60px;border:none; background: #4472C4;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="45"></td>
  <td style="width:65px;height:60px;border:none; background: #294EC7;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="65"></td>
  <td style="width:128px;height:60px;border:none; background: #DEEAF6;font-size: 0; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="128"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 15px; font-weight:bold; background: white">Tasking Benedicts.<br/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; background: white">Via di Roma, 32<br/></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" style="padding: 2px; font-size: 12px; background: white">Tel: 050 42581 / Fax: 050 2206529<br/></td>
 </tr>
 
 
 <tr>
     <td style="width:160px;height:7px;border:none; background: #9CC2E5;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px" width="160">
  <td style="width:17px;height:7px;border:none; background: #5B9BD5;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="17"></td>
  <td style="width:22px;height:7px;border:none; background: #BDD6EE;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="22"></td>
  <td style="width:32px;height:7px;border:none; background: #9CC2E5;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="32"></td>
  <td style="width:45px;height:7px;border:none; background: #4472C4;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="45"></td>
  <td style="width:65px;height:7px;border:none; background: #294EC7;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="65"></td>
  <td style="width:128px;height:7px;border:none; ;background: #DEEAF6;padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="128"></td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" style="text-align: justify; font-size:10; font-family:Arial; verdana; sans-serif; padding:0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm" width="400">
                    <p>This e-mail is confidential and may also contain privileged information. If you are not the intended recipient you are not authorised to read, print, save, process or disclose this message. If you have received this message by mistake, please inform the sender immediately and delete this e-mail, its attachments and any copies. Any use, distribution, reproduction or disclosure by any person other than the intended recipientis strictly prohibited and the person responsible may incur penalties. Thank you!<o:p></o:p></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </div>
 </div>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show the html and text, and the code you use to generate them. We cannot fix what we cannot see.

Comment: please [edit] your question instead of creating new "answers"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have put the code into the box. You can see i have inserted few columns to add 6 colors after my name. but in the text version i see large gap between my work position (Hardware technician) and the company name. this is my question. If i can sostitute this columns with (div) option, it is also a big help to me. i want to make this code more compampatible with other email clients.

Comment: Please remove all of these answers, including your code, and edit your original question.

Comment: You can edit your question instead of adding another "answer". I'm flagging this answer now. Use the "edit" link below your question. I have also included a comment with the link.

Comment: i think we have enough information to discuss about this matter

Comment: HI friends, not yet resolved my question? Are there anything to edit my question?